# Search specific numbers

Tags: awk, grep, numeric-data

im a list numbers in file and i would search 1 specific number in string

```
Es. 1 54 67 78 32
    11 4 67 89 90
    13 67 87 32 21
```

My search is 1

With awk or grep  commands out this numbers

```
1
11
13
21
```

```
grep -w 1
awk '/12/'
```

but not single 1

This is correct operations?
And for search for specific  2 numbers in 1 line?

Comment: I have a hard time understand what you want... `grep -w 1` outputs just the first `1` for your example string.

Comment: Do consider updating your question, adding exactly what commands you've tried and what the output was, along with the expected results.

Answer (score 1):

So you want any number containing the specified number? Add number patterns to the `1`, e.g.:

```
grep -ow '[0-9]*1[0-9]*' infile
```

Output:

```
1
11
13
21
```

#### Edit

As noted by Stéphane, this only works for positive integers. If you want a more general solution, something like what is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/658662/1331399) would be better. Below is a perlre grep version with the recommended regular expression:

```
grep -oP '[+-]?(0|[1-9]\d*)(\.\d*)?([eE][+-]?\d+)?' infile
```

Finding all numbers with a `1` in them is now a matter of passing the output to `grep 1`.

Comment: Might be worth clarifying that for `grep -w` a _word_ is a sequence of alphanumerical characters or underscores. On an input like `-21 12.13e-1`, it would return `21`, `12`, `13` and `1`.

Answer (score 0):

I have done by below 2 method

```
h=`awk '{print NF}' filename| sort | uniq| sort -nr | sed -n '1p'`
praveen@praveen:~$ for ((i=1;i<=$h;i++))
 do
 awk -v i="$i" '$i ~ /1/{print $i}' filename
done
```

out

```
1
11
13
21
```

Second method

sed -r "s/\s+/\n/g" filename | awk '/1/{print $0}'

```
1
11
13
21
```